# csvtolist function breaks when i create a new file variable in write mode

Tags: python, csv, file

```
from pathlib import Path
from csv import reader


base_folder = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
csvfilewrite = open(str(base_folder) + "/ourresults.csv", 'w')
csvfilewrite.write("")
csvfilewrite.close()
csvfileapp = open(str(base_folder) + "/ourresults.csv", 'a')


ListOfVals = ['.2.', '[89....1]']

def csvtolist(filename):
  with open(filename) as csvfile:
    csv_read = reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_read:
        print(row)
        ListOfVals.append(str(row).split(",")[0])
  return ListOfVals

def returnnumbers(Array): #Array Elements added from the Csv look like this "['2']"
    newstr = ''
    for i in Array:
        for j in range(0, len(i)):
            if i[j].isdigit():
                newstr += i[j]
        newstr += ", "
    return newstr

for i in range(1, 21):
    csvfileapp.write(str(i) + "\n")

csvtolist(str(base_folder) + "/ourresults.csv")
print(returnnumbers(ListOfVals) + "ugh")
csvfileapp.close()
```

i use the csvfilewrite variable to clear the csv file when the program opens.
The output i get if i keep it in write mode is
2, 891, ugh
if i either set the csvfilewrite in append mode, or comment out csvfilewrite, the csvfiletolist function will work as i intend. Heres a recreation of what shows up in the terminal in vs code:
...
['20']
2, 891, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 20, ugh

Why does the csvfiletolist function break like this?